# jquery .position().top sometimes fails

Tags: jquery

I've got this code here:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    if($("#error_email > p").text() != "")
    {
        var pos = $("#register_email").position();
        $("#error_email").css({
            top: pos.top-10 + "px",
            left: (pos.left) + "px",
            display: "inline-block"
        });
    }
});
```

For some reason very rarely variable pos gives me wrong answer, it's supposed to give me ~112px and sometimes it gives me ~700px and whole error message jumps to the place where it shouldn't be at, it works normally for like ~90% times as I tested though not 100%... What could be the problem?

Comment: Provide more context regarding your posted snippet. Do you call it on document ready/window load event? Can you provide a minimalistic sample to replicate issue? BTW, `pos.left` is wrong if `var pos = $("#register_email").position().top;`

Comment: ok,I'll fix this in a second

Comment: Same issue using $(window).on('load', handler);` instead of document ready?

Comment: $(window).on('load', handler); seems to work pretty well, at least for now, I'll need some more time to test if there really are no bugs with this

Comment: Ok I haven't gotten the same error again, thank you for help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
if($("#error_email > p").text() !=          "")
{
var pos =      $("#register_email").position();
    $("#error_email").css({
        top: (pos.top)-10 + "px",
        left: (pos.left) + "px",
        display: "inline-block"
    });
    }
  });
```